# Setting state after Object.keys map not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piece of data that I'm passing through props and is going to be used for a table, so I can display the opening and closing hours through all the week days.

The problem here is that I can't save this info in the state I created. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

        this.state = {
            weekDays: moment.weekdays(true),
            scheduleTime: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    const openingSchedule = this.props.operationDays; //data passed by props
    console.log(openingSchedule);

    let scheduleTime;
    console.log('1', scheduleTime)

    Object.keys(openingSchedule).map(key => { //obj through a map
        console.log('week day',key) //logs a week day, between monday and sunday
        console.log('schedule for ' + key, openingSchedule[key]) //logs OpenHours {endTime: '23:00', startTime: '08:00'}

        if (openingSchedule[key] && openingSchedule[key].startTime) {
            scheduleTime = openingSchedule[key].startTime;
            console.log('2', scheduleTime) // logs 08:00
        }
    })

    console.log('3', scheduleTime)
    this.setState({
        scheduleTime: scheduleTime
    })
    console.log('4', this.state.scheduleTime) //logs scheduleTime: []
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It makes no difference, @DacreDenny. :/

Comment: In state, you have an array `scheduleTime: []` however, in `componentDidMount`, you replace it with a time value. So your render might break. try `scheduleTime = [ scheduleTime ]; this.setState({ scheduleTime })`. Also, `setState` is an async function. So you will not get updated value here: `console.log('4',`. If you want to do something after state is updated, try `this.setState({...}, () => { // your code })`

Comment: The setState function is not synchronous so it is normal that the log 4 is still empty at the time of execution: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: As @loopingz said, the setState is an async and the console.log wont work here. You can write the console log in render() method and check the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check the value of `this.state.scheduleTime` just after calling the `setState` method and get the new value as your component has not been re-rendered yet.

```
this.setState({
    scheduleTime: scheduleTime
})
console.log('4', this.state.scheduleTime) //logs scheduleTime: []
```

Or you check the new value in the `componentDidUpdate` method, or you can write it like this:

```
this.setState({
    scheduleTime: scheduleTime
}, () => console.log('4', this.state.scheduleTime))
```

Comment: Okay, like that I can see that the value was indeed stored!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `setState` in async. It would set immediately, you can use callback e.g.

```
this.setState({scheduleTime}, () => {console.log(this.state.scheduleTime)})
```